# Reuse Vue.js stored into the DB

Tags: javascript, database, laravel, vue.js, crud

I'm trying to build a simple website builder that allow  users to save their generated html created with Vue component and see it at a certain URL.
Because of it I have to store and retrieve the html generated but I have some problems with retrieving of the code. Here is my step:

When user click "save" this function is fired, that select the portion of HTML that include the "website" built by the user:

```
 saveBuilders: function () {
            let pages = [];
            let builders = $('[id*="builder-container-"]');

            $.each(builders, function (key, builder) {
                let singleElem = $(builder).attr('id');
                pages.push(clearElement.html());
            });

            this.storeInDb(pages);
        },
```

```
storeInDb: function (pagesList) {
            axios.post("/landing-page/store", {
                name: this.name,
                description: this.description,
                html: pagesList
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                   console.log('Cool');
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('ERROR', error.response);
                });
        },
```

The Axios request is handled by this function that store the html portion in DB

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $data = $request->all();

        $html = $data['html'];
        $landingPage = new LandingPage();
        $landingPage->name = $data['name'];
        $landingPage->description = $data['description'];
        $landingPage->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $landingPage->html = json_encode($html);

        try {
            $landingPage->save();
            return 'true';
        } catch (exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    }
```

Now when the user visit a certain URL, for keep thing simple suppose is **example.it/website/0**, this function is fired:

```
     public function show($landing_id)
        {
            try {
                $landingPage = LandingPage::where([
                    'id' => $landing_id,
                    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
                ])->first();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $landingPage = null;
            }

            if ($landingPage != null) {
                //GET THE HTML
                $page = json_decode($landingPage->html);
                return view('landing_page.show')->with('page', $page)
            } else {
                abort(404, 'Error');
            }


        }
```

And this the blade where I'm trying to re-create the Vue.js environment

```
<body>
    <span id="countdown"></span>


    <div id="builder-pagina">
        <builder>
            {!! $page !!}}
        </builder>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/landing_page/app.js')}}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I thought that having the html generated by vue similar to something like that into the DB...

```html
<div data-v-29b64d26="" >
    <h1>This piece of code was stored into my DB</h1>
    <div data-v-56f62f0a="">
    </div>
</div>
```

...you could create everything working simply by pasting the code and by using the same js file used for compiling vue.js.

I've tried pass the entire code by props but is not working. Also tried with slot. Any suggestions?

Comment: You really have not provided enough code for us to assist you.

Comment: Can you please explain more on what your problem is? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: sorry for being vague,I added more code now.